# OS.STAT().ST_SIZE gives me incorrect size in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

os.stat doesn't give me correct output I only get 8192 byte for every file. Code below

```
import os

path = "C:\\"

filelist = os.listdir(path)

for i in filelist:
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, i)):
        print os.path.join(path, i), "is DIR"
    else:
        # fs = filesize
        fs = os.stat(path).st_size
        # fs = os.path.getsize(path)

        print os.path.join(path, i), "size is", fs
```

Here is output:

```
C:\$Recycle.Bin is DIR
C:\Config.Msi is DIR
C:\Documents and Settings is DIR
C:\hiberfil.sys size is 8192
C:\pagefile.sys size is 8192
C:\PerfLogs is DIR
C:\Program Files is DIR
C:\Program Files (x86) is DIR
C:\ProgramData is DIR
C:\Python27 is DIR
C:\Recovery is DIR
C:\shared.log size is 8192
C:\System Volume Information is DIR
C:\Users is DIR
C:\vcredist_x86.log size is 8192
C:\Windows is DIR
```

Why the biggest number is 8192? All files that are not dir have much bigger size than that. Output is the same for os.stat(path).st_size and os.path.getsize(path). Thanks in advance.

Comment: `os.stat(path)` != `os.stat(os.path.join(path, i))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to `os.path.join(path, i)` when checking the file size with `os.stat()`, so you always get the size for C:\ (which is 8192, windows specific stuff). Fixed script:

```
import os

path = "C:\\"

filelist = os.listdir(path)

for i in filelist:
    filepath = os.path.join(path, i)
    if os.path.isdir(filepath):
        print filepath, "is DIR"
    else:
        # fs = filesize
        fs = os.stat(filepath).st_size

        print filepath, "size is", fs
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```py
def calc_folder_size(directory):
    # https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-size-of-folder-using-python/
    # assign size
    size = 0
    
    # get size
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for f in files:
            fp = os.path.join(path, f)
            size += os.path.getsize(fp)

    size = int(size)

    # convert to GB
    if (size / 1e+9) > 0.001:
        size = size / 1e+9
        size = str(size) + " GB"
    else: 
        # convert to MB
        size = size / 1e+6
        size = str(size) + " MB"

    return size
```

At least most of the time. Sometimes it doesn't agree with what Windows calculates, but it is pretty close when they are not the same.